# How to solve this question subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Answer true or false to each of the following questions. If a statement is true, prove it. If a statement is false, give a counterexample.

1. For all sets $A$,$B$ and $C$: IF $A ⊆ B$ and $A ⊆ C$, Then $A ⊆ (B ∩ C)$
2. For all sets $A$ and $B$, if $|A| \le |B|$, then $A ⊆ B$

Comment: 1 is true- but 2 is false.

Comment: can u add the prove plz @voldemort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Let $A \subset B$ and $A \subset C$.

To show: $A \subset B \cap C$.

Let $x \in A$. Then $x \in B$ as $A \subset B$. Similarly, $x \in C$.

So, $A \subset B \cap C$.

1. Let $A=\{1\}$, and $B=\{a,b\}$. Then $|A| \leq |B|$ but $A$ is not a subset of $B$.

Comment: thx so mush but why the second one is false? can u give me the reason plz

Comment: @LamisNaji: The second one is false as $A$ is not a subset of $B$. $1 $ doesn't belong to the set $B$ :-P

Comment: thank u so so much dear <3

Answer (score 0):

For the first one: Suppose $x \in A$. We are given that $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C $. So, if $x \in A$, then $x \in B$ and $x \in C $. This implies that $x \in B \cap C $. So, your first claim is true.

The second one is false! Hint: $B= (0,1)$, $A = \mathbb{R} $

Comment: thank u so much but why the second one is false?